# Hashmap equivalent in C++

Tags: java, c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I have an application (in C++) in which I need to have a set of pairings between Strings and Integers, i.e:

```
("david", 0)
("james", 1)
("helen", 2)
...
```

If we use the java (key, value) definition, I need to be able to (1) search to see if a key exists in the map and (2) retrieve the value associated with a given string (key).When working in java, I found that the HashMap type could handle everything that I needed.

I would like to do the same but in C++. I did some googling around and found that in the C++ 2011 library there is an unordered_map type that replicates this. 
I was curious as to whether this was the best approach.

In my application I have the following rules on the collection

1. The Integers are always sequential (as per the example) and start at 0.
2. The Integer Values never change.
3. The Map is created at the start of the application and doesn't change, i.e. it's Immutable.
4. There are no duplicates of the string keys.
5. Upon creation of the map, I don't know how many keys (and by extension integer values) I'm going to need to use. One of the parameters for my application is the directory of a text file which contains the list of words to be used.
6. I don't care about start up time costs associated with this. I need the primary task (i.e. containsKey(..) and get(key) to be as fast as possible). And it will be called A LOT. The application is centered on processing large text corpora (i.e. Wikipedia) and forming co-occurence matrices between words/documents.

I thought that instead of having both the integer and string stored, that instead store the strings in some list type and then return the index back, i.e. 
data = { "david", "james", "helen", ... }

and then something like find_Map(data, key) to return back the index(value) that it's located with. I thought this could be speed up by first sorting into ascending order and applying a searching alogrithm. But again, that's just a guess.

I do appreciate that this is a common problem and that many different approaches exist. I'm going to code up a few different ideas but thought it would be best to ask the group first to see what you guys thought.

Comment: you should reword the question as you are confusing key with value - e.g., when you say "retrieve the key associated with the given string" - and here I thought the string was the key.

Comment: Cheers @davidback - will do.

Comment: U can look for struct.

Comment: BTW - assuming you've measured your program and know for sure that the two operations contains() and find() are where the time is spent and that's why you need them as fast as possible - it is also necessary to know things like how many lookups are successful vs misses.  In other words, is it more likely the key is found when searched, or not found?  In general though, nothing wrong with unordered_map unless you're _really_ time constrained.

Comment: @Arun - indeed, I thought that having the data in an ordered list type would be better than storing the integer values (which here may be redundant given it's sequential). Again, just a thought, not a critique of your suggestion.

Comment: Notice when working with strings the string comparison is expensive.  Ordered_map works with hashes - then verifies with a string compare.  Your hand-brewed data structure, if any, ought to work with hashes too.  But then you're talking about how to make a fast hash - and that depends on your strings.

Comment: @user3053801 - in your example above the integers - though compact - are _not_ sequential in terms of the keys (assuming an alphabetical sort).  (E.g., "james" is _after_ "Helen" alphabetically.)  So a structure sorted by key (i.e., string) will still need to store the values (i.e., int).  Unless your example is wrong.

Comment: @user3053801 - be careful, when comparing Java to C++ - in talking about a "list" type.  In Java (and C#) the "list" type is an array with 0(1) indexing.  In C++ it is a list with O(n) indexing.  (Well, ArrayList in Java anyway.  LInkedList is a linked list.)

Comment: I suggest removing the Java tag ad this has very little to do with Java. And also be consistent with your variable names: there is no such thing called Integer in C++.

Comment: @PasserBy - I was speaking about the classification of the actual number, not it's implementation in either Java or C++, but I definitely take your point and will be more transparent in future posts. 

Re Java: disagree, I wanted to replicate the actions of a java type and I was hoping to gain guidance from two fronts: Java/C++ Developers and sole C++ Developers. But again, I will take that into consideration for future posts. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can use `unordered_map<string,int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of data you want to store, there are two possibilities:

- For a semi-large amount of data, I think a `std::unordered_map<string, int>` will do just fine
- If you want to work with really large amounts of data, it could be helpful to think about more dedicated data structures for string storage, e.g. tries, where strings with a common prefix get stored in a common subtree. This could also improve your space usage, since the data gets *kind of* compressed. The most efficient implementation I know of is the [marisa-trie](https://github.com/s-yata/marisa-trie) also used in the python pytries package.

Comment: What exactly is `unordered_list`?

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is of course `std::unordered_map`. However, for more functionality and automatic index consistency we can involve `boost::multi_index_container`.

for example:

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

// Define a custom container type
using my_map = boost::multi_index_container<
    // It holds StringValue objects
    StringValue,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        // first index is called by_string, is a unique hashed index with constant time lookuo
        bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<by_string>, bmi::member<StringValue, std::string, &StringValue::str>>,

        // second index is called by_value, is a unique hashed index with constant time lookup
        bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<by_value>, bmi::member<StringValue, int, &StringValue::value>>,

        // second index is called ordered_by_value, is a unique ordered index with logarithmic time lookup
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<ordered_by_value>, bmi::member<StringValue, int, &StringValue::value>>
    >
>;
```

In this example, my_map is defined as a container which:

- Holds `StringValue` objects
- Maintains a hashed unique index by the object's `str` member
- Maintains a hashed unique index by the object's `value` member
- Maintains an ordered unique index by the object's `value` member, in case we wish to enumerate by value (for instance)

Full example:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

// define a value object
struct StringValue
{
    std::string str;
    int         value;
};

// provide a way to stream the pair to an ostream
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, StringValue const& sv)
{
    static const char fmt[] = R"__({ "str": %1%, "value": %2% })__";
    return os << boost::format(fmt) % std::quoted(sv.str) % sv.value;
}

struct by_string
{
};
struct by_value
{
};
struct ordered_by_value
{
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

// Define a custom container type
using my_map = boost::multi_index_container<
    // It holds StringValue objects
    StringValue,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        // first index is called by_string, is a unique hashed index with constant time lookuo
        bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<by_string>, bmi::member<StringValue, std::string, &StringValue::str>>,
        // second index is called by_value, is a unique hashed index with constant time lookup
        bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<by_value>, bmi::member<StringValue, int, &StringValue::value>>,
        // second index is called ordered_by_value, is a unique ordered index with logarithmic time lookup
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<ordered_by_value>, bmi::member<StringValue, int, &StringValue::value>>
    >
>;

template<class Array>
struct ArrayEmitter
{
    const Array& array;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ArrayEmitter const& em) {
        const char* sep = " ";
        os << "[";
        for (auto&& item : em.array) {
            os << sep << item;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        return os << " ]";
    }
};

template<class Array>
auto emit_as_array(Array&& arr)
{
    return ArrayEmitter<std::remove_cv_t<Array>> { arr };
}

int main()
{
    my_map mm { { "B", 3 }, { "D", 1 }, { "A", 4 }, { "C", 2 } };

    // assert that we can't violate the indecies
    auto ib = mm.insert(StringValue{"E", 1});
    assert(ib.second == false);

    // iterate by string
    std::cout << "print by value index:\n";
    std::cout << emit_as_array(mm.get<by_string>()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nprint by value index unordered:\n";
    std::cout << emit_as_array(mm.get<by_value>()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nprint by value index ordered:\n";
    std::cout << emit_as_array(mm.get<ordered_by_value>()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nfind an element by value in constant time:\n";
    auto&& name = mm.get<by_value>().find(2)->str;
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
print by value index:
[ { "str": "B", "value": 3 }, { "str": "D", "value": 1 }, { "str": "A", "value": 4 }, { "str": "C", "value": 2 } ]

print by value index unordered:
[ { "str": "B", "value": 3 }, { "str": "D", "value": 1 }, { "str": "A", "value": 4 }, { "str": "C", "value": 2 } ]

print by value index ordered:
[ { "str": "D", "value": 1 }, { "str": "C", "value": 2 }, { "str": "B", "value": 3 }, { "str": "A", "value": 4 } ]

find an element by value in constant time:
C
```

Documentation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your post! 
I'm still very new to C++ so I'm going to have to read over this a few times (some of the syntax I'm not familiar with yet. 
But again, thanks heaps - I'm hoping I'll be able to 'read' and understand this soon.